# Why won't this list sum?

Tags: python, list

In math class we are learning about 'Mean Average Deviant' and the calculators we have do not have any applications to automatically calculate the answer. So to help with homework I have been trying to make a script so all I have to do is enter the elements provided. I put the elements into a list but I am having a problem with summing the list to make an average

```
    N = raw_input("Number of Elements: ")

Elements = []
'''
Phase 1
'''
while len(Elements) != int(N):
    item = raw_input("Element: ")
    Elements.append(item)
    print len(Elements)

Average = sum(Elements)
```

When I test my code I get an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryan\Desktop\PythonTesting\MeanAverageData.py", line 12, in <module>
    print sum(Elements)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` returns a string. Instead, change the `raw_input` to `int(raw_input())`:

```
N = raw_input("Number of Elements: ")

Elements = []
'''
Phase 1
'''
while len(Elements) != int(N):
    item = raw_input("Element: ")
    Elements.append(item)
    print len(Elements)

Average = sum(Elements)
```

`int(raw_input())` only takes integer input, and will raise an error otherwise.

```
>>> int(raw_input('Enter your input: '))
Enter your input: 5 #Doesn't raise an error
>>> int(raw_input('Enter your input: '))
Enter your input: "Hello World!" #Does raise an error
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the list as a float first (Note: this will only work if all the strings *can* be cast as floats):

```
>>> print sum(map(float, Elements))
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Elements.append(item)
```

to

```
Elements.append(int(item))
```

or

```
Elements.append(float(item))
```